# Why counter tag is not working as expected in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, template-engine

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2619/

According to above snippet if we access `{{ counter_var }}` in template after initializing it should return previous count. But in my case it does not return anything.

template code

```
<div class="question_number pull-left">Q{% counter %}. </div>
...
<script>var no_of_questions={{ counter_var }}</script>
```

Even I tried by setting context variable counter_var from view as `{'counter_var':0,...}` then it returns '0'.

How to get it working so that it returns previous counter?
e.g.

```
Q1. 
Q2.
```

then `counter_var` should return 2 instead of nothing.

Django: 1.8.6
Python: 2.7

Edit:
Template tag is registered and it prints correctly `Q<count>.` except `counter_var` .

Comment: Have you registered the tag? It's not clear from your question whether you did, because if all you're doing is using `counter` in your template then it will not work.

Comment: Yeah I have registered and it gives correct count except count_var.

Comment: if you  use `<script>var no_of_questions="{{ counter_var }}"</script>`, with double quotes, does it make any change?

Comment: @doru It doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging some time this is the code can be used to get it working.

```
#Adapted from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2619/

@register.tag(name='counter')
def do_counter(parser, token):
    """
    Counter tag. Can be used to output and increment a counter.

    Usage:
    - {% counter %} to output and post-increment the counter variable
    - {% counter reset %} to reset the counter variable to 1
    - {% counter last %} to access the last counter variable without incrementing

    """
    try:
        tag_name, request = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        request = None

    if request == 'reset':
        reset = True
        last = False
    elif request == 'last':
        last = True
        reset = False
    else:
        reset = False
        last = False

    return CounterNode(reset, last)


class CounterNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, reset, last):
        self.reset = reset
        self.last= last

    def render(self, context):
        # When initializing or resetting, set counter variable in render_context to 1.
        if self.reset or ('counter' not in context.render_context):
            context.render_context['counter'] = 1

        # When resetting, we don't want to return anything
        if self.reset:
            return ''
        # When ask for last, return previous count
        if self.last:
            return context.render_context['counter']-1

        counter = context.render_context['counter']

        # Increment counter
        context.render_context['counter'] += 1

        # Return counter number
        return counter
```

The problem is that in latest django( at least 1.8.6) context variable can not be updated using template tag, so I  have to access the render_context variable created during rendering phase.

I have added on [Guthub gist](https://gist.github.com/sonus21/0ebd1b894ec837c8f8b2).